# Replace arabic Letter in database

Tags: sql-server, database, replace, arabic

When changing the letter (ي) at the word to the letter (ى) changes and there is no problem, but the problem in changing the letter (ي) in the middles of the letter?

Is there a solution to ignore the  middles of the letter?

```
DECLARE @FullName        VARCHAR(100)
SET @FullName = 'عبدالله عيد محمد علي'

Select @FullName, REPLACE(@FullName,'ى ','ي ')
```

> -- عبدالله عيد محمد علي
>
> -- عبدالله عىد محمد على

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using their Unicode equivalents

```
Select NCHAR(1740) as N'ي فارسي - Persian Ye', 
       NCHAR(1610) as N'ي عربي - Arabic Ye',
       NCHAR(1705) as N'ك فارسي - Persian Ke',
       NCHAR(1603) as N'ك عربي - Arabic Ke'
```

Such as

```
DECLARE @FullName  NVARCHAR(100)
SET @FullName = N'عبدالله عيد محمد علي'
Select @FullName, REPLACE(@FullName, NCHAR(1610), NCHAR(1740))
```

With this output
[image]

Comment: what should i do with that query i didn't understand

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, very clear (and working) answer. Thank you for your help and thank you for your time .

Comment: I have the same problem. and replacement seems to be OK. But when I used it in insert or update script it did nothing and saved original phrase. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `STRING_SPLIT` ,`STUFF` and `REVERSE` to split the string by spaces and then replace the last occurrence of a character in each word. And then you can use `STRING_AGG` to concatenate back with spaces.

```
DECLARE @FullName NVARCHAR(100)
SET @FullName = 'testexecution testexecution'

SELECT STRING_AGG(VALUE,' ') AS UpdatedFullName FROM
( 
SELECT STUFF(VALUE, LEN(VALUE) +1 - CHARINDEX('t', REVERSE(VALUE)), 1, 'k') AS VALUE   -- Replace last occurence of 't' with 'k'
from STRING_SPLIT(@FullName,' ')
) AS ReplacedResult
```

**NOTE: This will require SQL Server 2017 or higher to work**

Also your database seems to use multiple languages so I'd suggest to use `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` to support [Unicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: it look good for me, but if i want to check the last letter in each word in repetitions like `SET @FullName = 'عبدالله عيد علي محمد علي'`

Comment: @AhmedAlkhteeb I've updated my answer. Please note that you'll require SQL-Server 2017 or higher for this to work

Comment: sorry but it not working this time  SQL Server Management Studio      15.0.18142.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      15.0.1389.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.18362.1
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.18362.0
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      10.0.18362

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query, by replacing `[Table_name]` and `[Field_name]` with your variables:

```
update [Table_name] 
set [Field_name] = REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST([Field_name] as nvarchar(max)) ,  NCHAR(1610), NCHAR(1740)),NCHAR(1603) , NCHAR(1705))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).